# What is the meaning of GID below 0?

Tags: macos

While working on a yosemite box I found that two user groups had GID value below 0.

```
$ dscl -plist . -readall /Groups PrimaryGroupID

<dict>
    <key>dsAttrTypeStandard:PrimaryGroupID</key>
    <array>
        <string>-2</string>
    </array>
    <key>dsAttrTypeStandard:RecordName</key>
    <array>
        <string>nobody</string>
        <string>BUILTIN\Nobody</string>
    </array>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>dsAttrTypeStandard:PrimaryGroupID</key>
    <array>
        <string>-1</string>
    </array>
    <key>dsAttrTypeStandard:RecordName</key>
    <array>
        <string>nogroup</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Is it valid? Does it have a special meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User and group IDs are unsigned, i.e. always positive. However, on [two's-complement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) systems, a signed value -1 is represented in the same way as the largest possible unsigned value – 65535 (0xFFFF) in 16-bit fields, 4294967295 (0xFFFF'FFFF) in 32-bit fields.

In some operating systems the "nobody" user has the largest possible UID – not special in the OS, merely chosen as the complete opposite to root having 0. Some programs choose to write this UID as -1 or `(uid_t) -1` instead of 4294967295.

(This does cause confusion when other programs use the same value to mean "no UID set"...)

Comment: thanks, make sense for -1. Any idea about the -2 ? Meanwhile i also found it on userID's (nobody)

Comment: That's the same thing.